# How to make application of Flex for Android?

Tags: android, apache-flex

Actually i have created one dashboard in flex. But now i want to integrate this dashboard or make same dashboard for Android.

How i can achieve this? I want to make dashboard for Android.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to start with tools.  [Flash Builder 4.5](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) is a good start, as it includes the [Flex 4.5 SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.5), which you will need to build mobile apps.

With Flash Builder, it is very easy to create a new mobile application: File -> New -> Flex Mobile application.

That is the easy part.  What about converting your existing app to work on mobile?  This is where it gets a bit more tricky and will rely on your mad development skills.  :)

You see, it is very rare that a browser or desktop Flex app will translate directly to a mobile device.  The navigation paradigm is different, (including touches without the mouse) and the screen size varies from device to device.  Consider phones and tablets.  Consider landscape and portrait mode.  Each of these profiles will likely make you think about your UI.

Hopefully, you already have good separation between your UI and your behavior.  That will make it a lot easier to develop your mobile app.  You can likely re-use the vast majority of your Actionscript code (behavior) with a new UI.  You might even be able to re-use some of your components.  In all, though, your UI will probably be new.  Note also that the mobile SDK is almost completely Spark, and old MX components can't be used in mobile.

I created a screencast of [building a quick mobile app](http://riarockstars.com/2011/02/24/mobile-smackdown-flex-edition/) that you might find useful.

I also wrote up a 2-part article about separation and sharing between [mobile](http://riarockstars.com/2011/03/16/presentation-model-and-multiple-screens-part-1/) and [other screens](http://riarockstars.com/2011/04/12/presentation-model-and-multiple-screens-part-2/).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi.....If i make dashboard in flash builder 4.5 then whether i am able to run that app. in Android phone as Android need .apk file....??????

Comment: @Smith: I don't understand the question.  Flash Builder will produce an APK file when you build a mobile application for Android.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful "Flex for Android " tutorial [here](http://coenraets.org/flexandroid90/FlexAndroid90Minutes.pdf)

You may want a good Intro to AIR for Mobile :

Watch it [here](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2010-develop/introduction-to-adobe-air-for-mobile/%29)